# Accessing resource file in test directory in Symfony

Tags: phpunit, symfony, file-location

Currently I have directory structure like:

```
src
-App
--MyBundle
---Service
----DefaultService
tests
-AppMyBundle
--files
---data.csv
--Service
---DefaultServiceTest
```

I'm writting test for a file reader and I added `data.csv` file for demo file for a test. In my test I need to get a path of that `data.csv` file. But I couldn't find any way of getting it. I have tried accessing it via `file_locator` service like:

```
$locator = $this->container->get('file_locator');
$path = $locator->locate('@AppMyBundle/Tests/files/data.csv');
```

and

```
$locator = $this->container->get('file_locator');
$path = $locator->locate('@AppMyBundle/files/data.
```

With no luck.
namespaces if necessary of my `DefaultService` is `App\MyBundle\Service` and for DefaultServiceTest is `App\MyBundle\Tests\Service`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outside from app/bundle system so try this code please:

```
$path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../tests/AppMyBundle/files/data.csv';
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. gives `InvalidArgumentException: Unable to find file "@AppMyBundle/Tests/files/data.csv"` error

Comment: Yea I thought about this option but also was thinking I could get a bit more independent path but I guess this will be the way I'll have to go

Comment: Giad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I used `$client->getContainer()->getParameter('kernel.root_dir')` like this:

```
$client = static::createClient();

$schemaPath = sprintf(
    '%s/../tests/MyBundle/Resources/rss2.xsd',
    $this->_client->getContainer()->getParameter('kernel.root_dir')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently doing this when writing unit tests (which parse an Excel file) using Symfony 5, PHPUnit 7.5. My approach is much simpler. My tests are structured this:

```
tests
- Service
-- ManifestReaderTest.php
-- testdata
--- import_test_good.csv
```

Then within my ManifestReaderTest class, I have the following:

```
$this->assertFileExists(__DIR__ . "/testdata/import_test_good.csv" );
```

This way, I'm not reliant on external classes or services.